# Pandas + Delete specific rows not by index

Tags: python, pandas

I've started learning pandas and have found an issue which I can't seem to resolve.
I am loading a data from a csv file and need to delete some rows matching a few strings.

CSV:

```
id fullname city  tst
999      bbb  CIT  aaa
888      bbb  CIT  aaa
777      xxx  JJJ  aaa
```

What I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('zzz.csv')

#to_drop = ['xxx', 'aaa']

df = df.drop('xxx',axis=0)
```

but I am getting the error below:

```
KeyError: "['xxx'] not found in axis"
```

What I am missing here? Also, what if I want to pass a list and delete all rows matching strings from the list? Example:

```
to_drop = ['xxx', 'aaa']

df = df.drop(to_drop,axis=0)
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comment above, you can use a boolean expression to choose rows. As for what's wrong with your attempt, is that you did not set an index, which is required by `drop`.  Try: `df.set_index("fullname").drop("xxx", axis=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
df = df[df.fullname!='xxx']
```

and for a list:

```
names=['xxx','bbb']
df = df[~df.fullname.isin(names)]
```

the `~` operator means "not"